# How can i create custom YMM in magento?

Tags: magento

We are developing a online store for car auto parts
So that we need to filter product on the base of year,make and model attribute. 
 For that i create custom module  
 Modules block code goes here...


 `public function getYears(){

    $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'year'); 
    $option = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true);
    return  $option;
}
 public function getMake(){

     $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'make'); 
     $option = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true);
     return     $option;
    }

 public function getModel(){
     $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'model'); 
     $option = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true);
     return $option;    
}


}`

Via above function i get my configurable products attributes option and values depend on the basis of these attribute selection i want to show products on the home page? 
How can  i do?
  >Thanks in advance..